# How to play a video in a macOS application with swift?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avkit

I'm trying to get a video I have in my project to play in my macOS application using swift. Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var player : AVPlayer!
    var avPlayerLayer : AVPlayerLayer!

    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayer: AVPlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Background", ofType:"mp4") else {
            debugPrint("Not found")
            return
        }

        let playerURL = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerView = AVPlayerView()
        playerView.player = playerURL
        playerView.player?.play()
    }
}
```

I also have an AVPlayerView in my storyboard that I have connected to my viewcontroller.

It builds and runs fine but when I run it nothing shows up. I just get a black screen.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you create a local AVPlayerView but do nothing with the AVPlayerLayer outlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let playerView = AVPlayerView()
```

Instead of configuring the player view that is in your interface, you make a whole new separate player view — and then you throw it away.

Comment: Matt is on the money as always. To the OP, do you understand what you need to do to fix it? Do you have an `AVPlayerView` in your storyboard and attached to your `IBOutlet`?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it. Thanks!